# Get text from span (Whatsapp Web)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Python with Selenium and I would like to capture the username from the last message in a whatsapp group conversation. I tried it in several ways but I couldn't.

Ex:
I would like to get the text "Nay"from this part and store it in a variable.

```
<span dir="auto" class="FMlAw FdF4z _3Whw5">Nay</span>
```

[Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYWHf.png)

I tried:

```
 texto1 = post[ultimo].find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class_name = 'FMlAw FdF4z _3Whw5']").text
```

But i get an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I achieved relative success with the code below but in addition to copying the user's name, this also copied the messages

```
texto1 = post[ultimo].find_element_by_class_name("_3Whw5").text
```

Sorry, I'm using Google Translate.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the output of the last func look like? DOes in come in predictable format so that you could strip the username from the string? E.g. `texto1 = ['username','message1','message']` leading to the solution `texto1 = " ".join(texto1[1:])`.

Comment: Try using `.innerText`, and if that doesn't work then use `.outerText` and parse for your string.

Comment: //span[@class_name should be //span[@class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#get all messsages as a list
messages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'message-in focusable-list-item')]/following::span[contains(@class,'selectable-text')]/span")

#reverse the list so you can get easier the last element 
messages.reverse()

#last element becomes the first - now you can use it, I printed for the purpose of testing
print(messages[0].text)
```

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct?